# JQuery on url click change image

Tags: jquery, image

i have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>
<ul id="image_list">
    <li><a href="images/casting1.jpg" title="Casting on the Upper Kings">Upper Kings</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/casting2.jpg" title="Casting on the Lower Kings">Lower Kings</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">Big Horn</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/fish.jpg" title="Catching on the South Fork">South Fork</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/lures.jpg" title="The Lures for Catching">Lures</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
<p id="gallery">
    <img src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery area" id="image">
</p>
</section>
</body>
```

How can i change image of  p id="gallery" to the href of the link clicked in the ul id="image_list" and title?

I have this Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).find("href").attr("src"); //gets href
        var title_desc = $(this).text(); //gets title

        $('#image_list').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  //disables the heperlink
            $('#caption').replaceWith(title_desc); //changes the title
            $("#image").attr("src", imgUrl) //changes the href
        });
    })
});
});
```

This code gets things changed but with image not found replacements and title goes away. like if the get image and title is wrong

Comment: `title` is an attribute, so you cannot select it with `#title` in find.

Comment: @john i would suggest you to create breakpoint in firebug in your script and at points see the value of `this` and in console try to access the values and you would be able to solve it the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much selection and you do not need to call a `click()` within your click event. I would suggest this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/59m6p1qw/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image_list a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var imgUrl = $(this).attr("href"); //gets href value
        var title_desc = $(this).attr("title"); // gets the title value
        $('#caption').html(title_desc); //changes the title
        $("#image").attr("src", imgUrl) //changes the source
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Hopefully you feel strong enough about it to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#image_list li a').click(function(){
    imgUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    title_desc = $(this).attr('title');

    $('#caption').text(title_desc);
    $('#image').attr('src', imgUrl);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: this changes the image correctly ,but the title only changes once, and if you keep clicking the image changes but the title stays the same. and not the same format as it was